# Failing to log into Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login

I tried upgrading my Ubuntu from 11.10 to the new 12.04 and I had to force my computer off because it froze. I thought I had to restart the upgrade process, but apparently it somehow finished upgrading.  Unfortunately, now I can't log in.

There is a black terminal-like screen asking for an "Ubuntu Username" and "password". I keep keying in my computer name and password in  different ways, but it keeps saying it's invalid.

I don't want to restart my artworks that I worked days on.

How can I get on the new Ubuntu without losing my stuff?

(note my laptop doesn't use f# keys)

Answer (score 0):

you have a couple questions in there, so let's break this down one at a time:

1. **Try logging in again**:

   Just to cover all your bases, have you checked to see if caps lock, etc. might be turned on when entering your password?
2. **Accessing your files**:

   Boot from a LiveCD and select "Try Ubuntu" (don't install). You can "rescue" your files by mounting the disk, and copying them to an external harddrive or a usb key. Depending on the permissions of your home folder you may need to use `sudo` to copy things over. (e.g., open a terminal window and enter `gksu nautilus` to open a file browser with sudo privileges)
3. **Restoring/Reinstalling the system**:

   Once you have all your files safely backed up you can try fixing the system (although, I'm not sure how in your case. You can try booting into a recovery shell as root, and change the user password see [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrativeroot-password)). Or, with your files safe, you could just reinstall.